# Initial openLDAP Configuration

Tags: configuration, openldap, ubuntu-11.10

I have been trying to set up my first real openLDAP instance for a login page and I have run into a large problem getting it to start intially. Every time I start LDAP and do an initial search I get a response that indicates that I have no domain set up:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> with scope baseObject
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: namingContexts 
#

#
dn:
namingContexts: dc=nodomain

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

However, my understanding is that if I edit /etc/ldap/slapd.conf to change the suffix I can get the server to start with a domain of my choosing. To that end I have the following slapd.conf:

```
# slapd.conf - configuration
include /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
pidfile /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
argsfile /var/run/slapd/slapd.args
loglevel any
modulepath /usr/lib/ldap
# modelpath /usr/local/libexc/openldap
moduleload back_hdb
######################
# DB configuration   #
#####################
database hdb
suffix "dc=test,dc=com"
rootdn "cn=root,dc=test,dc=com"
rootpw secret
directory /var/lib/ldap
# directory /usr/local/var/openldap-data
index objectClass,cn eq
########    
# ACLs #
########
access to attrs=userPassword
       by anonymous auth
       by self write
       by * none
access to *
       by self write
       by * none
```

When I run slapd with debugging switched to config I get some output that I *think* indicates that my config file is not being loaded; but I am not entirely sure what to look at or look for at this point, and none of the tutorials I have found online have worked around this issue. If it helps anyone, I have done all of my installs and re-installs using apt-get slapd on a ubuntu-11.10 box. This is probably just a dumb mistake caused by my own ignorance, but I am at a loss to find it at this point.

Also I am attaching the startup debug output below just in case someone finds it useful.

```
@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.25 (Nov 14 2011 21:34:11) $
    buildd@yellow:/build/buildd/openldap-2.4.25/debian/build/servers/slapd
loaded module back_hdb
module back_hdb: null module registered
index objectClass 0x0004
slapd starting
```

Comment: Show us the command line for the search.

Comment: ldapsearch -x -b '' -s base '(objectclass=*)' namingContexts

My understanding is that that command should list all the available contexts on the server. I have also tried

    ldapsearch -x -W -D 'cn=root,dc=test,dc=com' -b "" -s base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the -H switch with ldapsearch to specify what server to search.

The listeners are set up via the HOST_LIST parameter in /opt/symas/etc/openldap/symas-openldap.conf  You can check this file to examine your current setup.  The default is to listen on the loopback address.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `slaptest` utility to debug your `slapd.conf`. See the documentation.

Comment: Slaptest is fine:
    slaptest -v -f slapd.conf
    config file testing succeeded

Answer (score 0):

ldapsearch -x -h localhost -b "dc=test,dc=com"